# Tinkerpop Gremlin group by key and get latest

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I am creating 2 users(uid=1 & uid=2) with 2 versions each.

```
g.addV('user1').property('uid',1).property('version',1)
 .addV('user1').property('uid',1).property('version',2)
 .addV('user1').property('uid',2).property('version',1)
 .addV('user1').property('uid',2).property('version',2)
```

I want to get the latest version from each uid, I am using the `uid` as a `groupBy` key and getting the latest as shown

```
g.V().hasLabel('user1')
.group().by('uid').by(fold().order(Scope.local).by('version', Order.desc).unfold().limit(1)) //GraphTraversal<Vertex,Map<Object, Object>>
.flatmap(t -> t.get().values().iterator()) // convert to GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex>
//traverse out and get the path
.out('friend').path().by(elementMap())
```

1. Is the best approach for this requirement?
2. What would be the gremlin preferred way to convert the Map to a Vertex inside the flatmap rather than using the lambda? Suppose I want to add further steps after this.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you share the results you would like to get. Are you looking for something like this? gremlin> g.V().group().by('uid').by(values('version').max())
==>[1:2,2:2]

Comment: @KelvinLawrence  I would like to continue the traversal further  [g.V().group().by('uid').by(values('version').max())..out('friend').path().by(elementMap())]

Comment: You can make the group a side effect in that case by giving it a label
g.V().group('x').by('uid').by(values('version').max()).out()....

And then when you are done just assemble the final result.

Comment: Yes that is what i want. I assume that a second group side effect can be added to the out also, correct? eg [g.V().group('x').by('uid').by(values('version').max()).out().group('x').by('uid').by(....).path()...]. Thank you!

Comment: I'll type up a quick answer in case others have the same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `group` step has two modes. Without a label it acts as a barrier but with a label it acts as a side effect. You can have results flow through a group using your data as follows.

```
gremlin> g.V().group('x').by('uid').by(values('version').max())
==>v[42306]
==>v[42309]
==>v[42312]
==>v[42315]
==>v[42318]  

gremlin> g.V().group('x').by('uid').by(values('version').max()).cap('x')
==>[1:2,2:2]
```

You can add more traversal steps of course before you decide what you want to do with the group. Such as:

```
g.V().group('x').by('uid').by(values('version').max())out()...
```

Comment: I want to apply the .out() to the result of the grouped Vertices [1:2,2:2], not all the vertices. Is this possible?